# Scanner throwing java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found when processing large CSV file (750000 lines)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, data-processing

Hello I am currently processing a large Excel document containing the yearly temperatures of each of the world's cities over around 270 years and am receiving an error java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found after around 75000 lines. Each line has 8 elements in them which get stored in an arraylist of type city which has variables: CountryName, CityName, AvgTemp, MinTemp, MaxTemp, Longitude, Latitude and Year.
The method I am using to debug this is as follows:

```
 private static void FillPopulation(){
        Connection con = null;

        try{
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATA_BASE);
            Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(new File(EXCEL_TO_PROCESS));
            
            lineScanner.nextLine();
            
            while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
                String line = lineScanner.nextLine();
                Scanner rowScanner = new Scanner(line);
                rowScanner.useDelimiter(",");
                String year = rowScanner.next();
                String avgTemp = rowScanner.next();
                String minTemp = rowScanner.next();
                String maxTemp = rowScanner.next();
                String cityName = rowScanner.next();
                String countryName = rowScanner.next();
                String latitude = rowScanner.next();
                String longitude = rowScanner.next();
                if (avgTemp.equals("")) {
                    avgTemp = "0";
                 }
                 if (minTemp.equals("")) {
                    minTemp = "0";
                 }
                 if (maxTemp.equals("")) {
                    maxTemp = "0";
                 }
                String query = "INSERT INTO CityTemps VALUES('" + countryName + "', '" + cityName + "', " + year +", "+avgTemp+", "+maxTemp+", "+minTemp+", '"+latitude+"', '"+longitude+"')" ;
                System.out.println(query);
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                stmt.execute(query);

            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Im not sure what is causing this, any explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change `while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {` to `while (lineScanner.hasNextLine()) {`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch still has the same problem. The line it processes is ```1823,2.786,-20.343,23.233,Zhaodong,China,45.81N,125.77E``` and the next line that doesnt work is ```1823,12.164,3.729,18.618,Zhaotong,China,26.52N,103.88E```